# how can I get the account locked information via python web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, python

There is a command personal.listWallets in geth cli to get the account locked/unlocked status such as below:

```
> personal.listWallets[1]
{
  accounts: [{
      address: "0x175ec34c2b545a4e2195bfbfe03a82b67e594390",
      url: "keystore:///var/geth/keystore/UTC--2018-07-16T09-18-23.192773724Z--175ec34c2b545a4e2195bfbfe03a82b67e594390"
  }],
  status: "Locked",
  url: "keystore:///var/geth/keystore/UTC--2018-07-16T09-18-23.192773724Z--175ec34c2b545a4e2195bfbfe03a82b67e594390"
}
```

How can I get the similar account status from python web3 package or send the  same command to fetch the information via python web3?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you **have been activated personal rpc of your geth**, to do this programatically **without hardcoding the keystore file directory path** in **python**, do the following:

```
from web3 import Web3
import eth_keys
from eth_account import account

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1'))
address = '0x...'
password = 'password'

wallets_list = w3.geth.personal.list_wallets()
keyfile_path = (wallets_list[list(i['accounts'][0]['address'] for i in wallets_list).index(address)]['url']).replace("keystore://", "").replace("\\", "/")
keyfile = open(keyfile_path)
keyfile_contents = keyfile.read()
keyfile.close()
private_key = eth_keys.keys.PrivateKey(account.Account.decrypt(keyfile_contents, password))
public_key = private_key.public_key

private_key_str = str(private_key)
public_key_str = str(public_key)
```

You can extract other info from this file, too. I just extracted the private key and public key of an address as an example.